# How do I include additional kinds of boxes that are Tab-selectable

Tags: front-end, gui-construction, undocumented, boxes, eventhandler

Observe that `"PlaceHolder"` and `InputFieldBox` are known by the FE to respond to pressing the Tab key:

```
RowBox[{
 TagBox[
   FrameBox["placeholder"],
   "Placeholder"], " ", 
 DynamicModuleBox[{Typeset`i$$ = "x"}, 
    InputFieldBox[Dynamic[Typeset`i$$], String],
    DynamicModuleValues :> {}]}] // RawBoxes
```

Click on either box created by the code above and press Tab.  The selection will cycle through.  I would like to add a new class of box style that the FE would allow the user to tab through.

1. Where does the code live that tells the FE that `"PlaceHolder"` and `InputFieldBox` are boxes that should respond appropriately upon pressing the Tab key?
2. And, how can I append additional styles to this list so that the FE appropriately tabs through the added named style boxes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can utilize `Placeholder` option but it is undocumented.

```
{InputField[], Style[1, Placeholder -> True], Placeholder[1]}
```

If you insist of doing this via TagBox/TemplateBox mechanism then take a look at `"Placeholder"` tag styles: `CurrentValue[{StyleDefinitions, "Placeholder"}]` and create your own template.